# input изменяет размер блока

Tags: html, css, css3, input, layout

div без input:

```css
body {
  background: #001329;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 30px;

  color: white;
  background: #002754;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.flex-grow-6 {
  flex-grow: 6;
}

.flex-grow-3 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex-grow-6"></div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-grow-3"></div> <!-- div -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

div с input:

```css
body {
  background: #001329;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 30px;

  color: white;
  background: #002754;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.flex-grow-6 {
  flex-grow: 6;
}

.flex-grow-3 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex-grow-6"></div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-grow-3"> <!-- div -->
      <input> <!-- input -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы input не менял зармер div ?

Comment: .flex-item - flex-basis: 0;

Comment: @soledar10 не подходит. Невозможно изменять свойства height и width

Comment: eugene, height и width чего невозможно изменять?

Comment: @AlexDevTime, потому что к ним применено свойство flex-basis: 0

Comment: @eugene я спрашивал не почему, а какому элементу вам надо менять параметры и как вы это хотите менять. Потому что то вариант soledar'a прекрасно работает. И я не пойму что у вас не получается. Вам назвали правильный вариант.

Comment: @AlexDevTime, я хочу, чтобы input не изменял размер div и чтобы input был в высоту 50px. С flex-basis: 0 высота (height) input не изменяется через стили, а без flex-basis: 0 - изменяется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вариант, который вы хотели, чтоб input не  менял высоту родительского блока. Он ее не меняет, так как в .flex-item указана уже статическая высота. Если ее убрать, то будет родительский блок подстраиваться под input.
Также можно задавать input любую высоту и она меняется (input нарочно вылазит за границу, чтоб это продемострировать вам).

```css
body {
  background: #001329;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  color: white;
  background: #002754;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.flex-item input{
 height: 50px;
}

.flex-grow-6 {
  flex-grow: 6;
}

.flex-grow-3 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item flex-grow-6"></div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-grow-3"> <!-- div -->
    <input> <!-- input -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

используйте float для импута , overflow для блока и класс импуту добавьте и в css размер классу установите свойство сброса стандартных настроек импута(простите непомню название). если сам неперепутал чтото).